# Powershell cd sitecode not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, sccm

I am trying to run CD to SCCM site folder after Import-Module **ConfigurationManager.psd1** on a remote computer as a Non-Admin user. However I am gettting the following error:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName somecomputer -Credential Sccm\u6
[somecomputer]: PS C:\Users\u6\Documents> Import-Module ConfigurationManager.psd1
[somecomputer]: PS C:\Users\u6\Documents> cd 1SA:
cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '1SA' does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (1SA:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I can get around this issue by following the documentation given on this link: http://benef-it.blogspot.in/2013/04/solve-ps-drive-problem-with-sccm2012.html

But how can I do this programmatically from within powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the solution to this

```
New-PSDrive -Name $sitecode -PSProvider "AdminUI.PS.Provider\CMSite" -Root "$ENV:ComputerName" -Description "SCCM Site"
```

Running the above command creates the drive which you can subsequently use.

Refer: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5aee8b-a7ea-4b74-8b13-a2569b88bd5f/newpsdrive-returns-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?forum=configmanagersdk

Answer (score -2):

I don't think a folder can contain ":" in it's name. It really looks like the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry I had pasted the wrong command it was cd 1SA:, 1SA is the site code in sccm.

Comment: So what is the path you  are trying to cd into
C:\Users\u6\Documents\1SA ?
C:\Users\u6\Documents\1SA: ?
Does it exist?

Comment: Ok got the solution, which I have posted as answer. Actually 1SA: is drive in power shell corresponding to CMSite created. It was not available using the command given in answer it can be created and is accessible now.

Comment: `:` denotes a drive. In PowerShell a PSDrive does not have to be File System and can be other providers, for example a default PSDrive `HKLM:` uses the Registry Provider to map the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as a drive. The asker`s question they are attempting to connect to a SCCM site. Using the SCCM provider you can map a site as a drive.